# PHP list dir of html files with link to show in a div

Tags: php, jquery, file, html

I have a directory with several .html files.

Would like to read the list of files into a select list and when one is selected, display the file in a div.

Have no problem using jquery or whatever if that is what is required.

Comment: What have you tired? Where are you running into problems?

Comment: This reads more like a specification than a question.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I do not know how and have been searching for examples of how it can be done. Didn't know I was asking someone to write the next facebook app. I'll keep searching and you are free to keep moving. Thanks again.

Comment: That's a load off my mind. Phew, thanks!

Comment: The reason you are getting some unfriendly responses is because you aren't showing what kind of effort you've put into solving this problem. That's not to say you haven't, but your question should generally show the community that you have hit a roadblock, attempted to get past it, but just got stumped and have to seek advice. From our perspective, this question is structured like you want us to just do the work for you, rather than point you in the right direction to do your own work. You'll get much better responses if you show us what you've already tried and why it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks KingCoyote, that makes sense and I will try to form my "question" better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read directory with php, and populate select list, than onchange event of select you should read selected one and show it where you want.

just a simple example with iframe,

```
<?php
  $dir = ".";
  $dh = opendir($dir);
  echo "<select onchange='changePage(this)'>";
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>";
  }
  closedir($dh);
  echo "</select>";
?>
<br />
<iframe id="f" src="" height="600" width="800" ></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changePage(e) {
      var ifr = document.getElementById("f");
      ifr.src = e.value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you "ocanal"!! That will give me a great start! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I choose to use pure jQuery and the same idea as above. It was in the works, just took me a few minutes longer

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>File Select and Show example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src=jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#filesList").on('change', function(){
    $("#showMeTheFile").empty();
    var ourFile = $(this).val();
    $('#showMeTheFile').load(ourFile);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dir = "path/to/our/directory";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    //we need to build the select list before the while statement
    echo '<select id="filesList">';
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if(filetype($dir . $file) == 'file'){
        $splitFile = explode('.', $file);
        if($splitFile[1] = 'html'){               
          echo '<option value='.$file.'>'.$splitFile[0].'.'.$splitFile[1].'</option><br/>';
        }
      }
    }
    //we also need to close it after our while statment.
    echo '</select>';
    closedir($dh);
  }
}

?>
<div id='showMeTheFile'>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohgodwhy, thanks so much! Not only does it help but is a great learning tool. Thank you both for taking time out to help!